# Unable to allocate 29.0 MiB for an array with shape (3, 1267618) and data type float64

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB 
nb = MultinomialNB(alpha = 10) 
nb.fit(X_train_dtm, y_train)
```

It shows memory error while running this code.

Comment: Which line causes the problem?

Comment: Just wondering you should use transposed of the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

So, a `MemoryError` will occur when Python can't get a block of memory from the operating system. It seems unusual to be unable to allocate 29MB unless you're running this on a tiny computer.

One fix would be to use the `partial_fit` method over chunks of the data.